# chkdsk on external hard drive stucks at level 4

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk, bad-sectors

Running `chkdsk g: /f /r` on my 1 TB external hard drive with NTFS file format stucks at level 4. I let it run for 24 hours but there is no progress.

[image]

I tried to make a backup of its content but at a certain point, it goes into error so I suspect there should be some bad sectors to fix.

Any suggestion to fix the issue?

Comment: You have two options. Both start with buying a new drive of the same size or larger. The first option is to use a disk-level tool `dd_rescue` and clone the whole drive to the new. The other option is to copy all data file by file to the new drive.

Comment: In addition to the great advice @Robert is pointing you toward,  just know that I have both had dd (and dd_rescue) processes take ***WEEKS*** to complete when dealing with a ton of bad sectors.. even then you aren't going to get the stuff from those sectors.  If you need to run low level recovery, you really want a copy of that drive (as Robert points out) because the more you mess with it, the worse the problem will (probably) get.  If you can get the files you care really about *easily* without hitting the bad part of the drive, do that and start over with a new drive.

Comment: thank u both. I think your comments are worth being the answer maybe with some additional details ;-)